# AngularJS - one time binding generates watchers in ng-repeat inside table

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have no idea why this one-time binding is not working. Could you have a look and let me know if everthing is ok? I'm using angular 1.4+ (1.4.10 at the moment)

Controller:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('showcase.angularWay', ['datatables', 'ngResource'])
.controller('AngularWayCtrl', AngularWayCtrl);

function AngularWayCtrl($resource) {
    var vm = this;
    $resource('data.json').query().$promise.then(function(persons) {
        vm.persons = persons;
    });
}
```

View:

```
<article class="main-content">
<header class="article-header">
    <h1><i class="fa fa-play"></i>&nbsp;The Angular way</h1>
</header>

<section class="showcase">
    <tabset>
        <tab heading="Preview">
            <article class="preview">
                <div ng-controller="AngularWayCtrl as showCase">
                    <table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>FirstName</th>
                            <th>LastName</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="person in ::showCase.persons track by ::$index">
                            <td>{{ ::person.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ::person.firstName }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ::person.lastName }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </article>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="HTML">
</section>
```

data.json returns json that looks like this:
[{
    "id": 870,
    "firstName": "Foo",
    "lastName": "Whateveryournameis"
},
...
]

And in Batarang i see:

[image]

Comment: you don't need `track by` if you use one time binding on `::showCase.persons`.

Comment: unfortunatelly it didn't change anything. I changed it to this:

<tr ng-repeat="person in ::showCase.persons">
                                <td>{{ ::person.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ ::person.firstName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ ::person.lastName }}</td>
                            </tr>

Comment: what's your problem actually?

Comment: watcher counter remains the same. I expect it to drop down to almost 0 watchers when i use one time binding in this case...

Comment: It looks like it's the first digest cycle with ng-repeat items. Those items should disappear on the next cycle.